# MPEG2TS container format

Tags: video, containers, mpeg

Is there any document which explain the MPEG2TS container format.

Regards
Ankit Kapoor

Answer (score 1):

The standard is ISO/IEC 13818 Part 1.  This document covers the MPEG-2 Transport Stream and Program Stream formats.  Search for ISO/IEC 13818-1 and you'll find plenty of resources.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MPEG-2_Transport_Stream